# If C++17 and above guarantee that allocators must support overaligned types, does that mean we can avoid creating manually-aligned types?

Tags: c++, types, c++17, allocator, overaligned

Given a custom vector and using std::allocator for allocating, under C++17 and above do we still need to create an internal overaligned type OT using alignas, then allocate for OT, and reinterpret_cast OT* to T* before dereferencing the pointer on iterator operator*, in order to support overalignment of the type?

Or will std::allocator align correctly, and dereferencing T* be perfectly functional for returning a correctly overaligned reference to an element?

Thanks for any clarifications.

Comment: "_we still need to create an internal overaligned type OT using alignas, then allocate for OT, and reinterpret_cast OT* to T* before dereferencing the pointer on iterator operator*,_": I don't exactly follow what you are describing, but that sounds like UB to begin with.

Comment: All that requirement says is that allocators must support overalignment. So if you allocate OT it's working the same as before, and if you allocate T, you are still only guaranteed the alignment of T. Just to mention that the `reinterpret_cast` in there is complete nuts, when you could just have packed T into OT by aggregation as a member without any UB. Add an implicit cast operator, and you wouldn't even notice it's there.

Comment: "*in order to support overalignment of the type?*" It's not clear what this means in the context of the procedure you're talking about. That procedure only makes sense if `T` is *itself* not an overaligned type, but you want to allocate memory that is aligned to `OT`. But if that's true, then there is no "overalignment of the type" `T` because it is *not overaligned.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before C++17 it was implementation-defined whether `std::allocator` supports over-aligned types.

With [P0035](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html) for C++17 this was changed and now all types need to be supported. Which alignments an implementation supports for types in general is still implementation-defined, but you wouldn't be able to define a type with an unsupported alignment in the first place.

So, a `std::vector<T>` will correctly align its elements for type `T` even if it is over-aligned in C++17. I don't follow your explanation of the "old" way to achieve alignment, but before C++17 there was, absent the mentioned implementation-definedness, no way to get an over-aligned type into a `std::vector` with the standard *Allocator*. You had to write your own *Allocator* to support over-aligned types. You also always needed and still do need `alignas` to actually make your type `T` over-aligned.

However, the *Allocator* requirements in general to do not require that all over-alignments are supported and unfortunately allow alignment to be silently ignored. Therefore, if you use a different allocator than `std::allocator`, you must individually verify that it supports the alignment of your over-aligned type.